# Qt Quick 2 iOS Notch Avoidance

Tags: c++, ios, qt, qml

My App is fullscreen.

How do I avoid placing items behind the notch and home line on iOS devices with a notch when using QT Quick 2?

My app runs on devices with and without a notch and I'm trying to avoid a blank area on the top and bottom of devices that do not have a notch.

Comment: Put something there as a place holder and block it out with a clear rectangle?

Comment: Yes, but my app runs on devices without a notch too.
I don't want a blank space on the top and bottom of devices that do not have a notch

Comment: I target linux, windows, and android with Qt, but haven't done ios.  Is the notch on all ios?  If so, you can write a c++ function for retreiving the OS using  `#if defined(Q_OS_IOS)`.  How can you detect when the notch is present? If you can detect it, then you can make that place holder only visible when the notch is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Contacted QT Support and got the real answer.
Use the Safe Area Margins when running your app in fullscreen.

```
 #include <qpa/qplatformwindow.h>

 void MainWindowBackend::setWindow(QObject *window)
 {
      QWindow *qwin = qobject_cast<QWindow*>(window);
      QPlatformWindow *pWin = qwin->handle();
      QMargins safeArea = pWin->safeAreaMargins();
 }
```

also add

```
 QT += gui-private
```

in your pro file

Comment: Can you provide some more information on what *MainWindowBackend* is in your case?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is having the same problem.

First make your app not fullscreen on iOS, this will create black areas at the top and bottom of your app.

You can change the color of the black areas to better suit your app:

**notch.h**

```
#ifndef NOTCH_H
#define NOTCH_H

#include <QObject>

class Notch : public QObject{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Notch();
};

#endif
```

**notch.mm**

```
#include <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#include "notch.h"

Notch::Notch()
{
    //Top
    UIView *statusBar = (UIView *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:@"statusBar"];
    statusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.09 green:0.14 blue:0.19 alpha:1.0];

    //Bottom
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    app.windows.firstObject.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

Now just call Notch(); in your main.cpp file