# QML Change Color of iPhone Notch and Bottom Area

Tags: ios, qt, qml

How to change the color of the notch area using QML or Qt C++? The solutions provided here: [Qt Quick 2 iOS Notch Avoidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55537619/qt-quick-2-ios-notch-avoidance/55541002#55541002) do not work anymore.

I just want to replace the black areas with the same blue used in the title bar to get a better look and feel.

[image: Black Notch]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after a lot of reading I found the answer. The main idea is to get the safe margins from C++ world and transfer it to QML. There all the objects can me moved using anchors such that it looks great!

The according commit can be found here:
https://github.com/myzinsky/cloudLogOffline/commit/4d84cf7f1db852051f34afda71a7c536c4f1ddc9

Here the Result: [image: Final App]